# How to convert string into date format dd-MMM-yyyy format?

Tags: java

I have date in format dd-MMM-yyyy.  Now I want to add 30 days to it. How to do this?

Answer (score 3):

[`JodaTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) provides a great approach to this

```
new DateTime().addDays(30);
```

It can also easily convert to and from `java.util.Date` objects if you desire to use your date format. You could also achieve a similar result with [`Calendar`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html)

```
Calendar c = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(/*your date*/);
c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 30);
```

Comment: But I don't to add 30 days in todays date,I want to add 30 days in date given by user.

Comment: @user, you still can. The `DateTime` constructor accepts a java `Date`, e.g., `new DateTime(new Date());`

Comment: @user, to be crystal clear, you can use `Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").parse(string)` to create a `Date` from a string before supplying it to the `DateTime` constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Calendar`:

```
Date date = new Date();
try {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    date = format.parse(dateString);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 30);

    date = calendar.getTime();

} catch(ParseException e) {
    ...
}
```

However, if you want to make handling dates even more painless, I'd go with Johan's answer (use [`JodaTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)), but this will require use of a third-party library.

Comment: But I don't to add 30 days in todays date,I want to add 30 days in date given by user and user will give input date in format dd-MMM-yyyy

Comment: This doesn't add 30 days to today's date. It adds 30 days to the date you parse from `dateString`. The `Date date = new Date();` just initializes a new `Date` object; it's not strictly necessary. You could have also done `Date date = format.parse(dateString);`

Comment: I am not getting it. Please help me.

Comment: use vivian's code and test/debug. You will understand. There is nothing there to explain.